# $\sigma(n)$ is injective?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading about the sum function of divisors $\sigma(n)$, and the question arose as to whether this is injective. Does anyone know the answer? in case of being injective some idea for the demonstration? Thanks in advance. And I apologize if it turns out to be an obvious question, I have a suspicion that it is injective but I'm not sure.

Comment: $\sigma(14)=1+2+7+14=24$ and $\sigma(15)=1+3+5+15=24$

Comment: Oh, wow! Thank you very much for taking me out of the doubt.

Comment: In the future, you can either write a program to check that (if you can) or simply check https://oeis.org/ . Googling "oeis sum of divisors" finds https://oeis.org/A000203

Comment: @shibai: I suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Oliver I could, but I like Drei's answer better :)

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Comment: I'd add that the function is not surjective either. Meaning that there are numbers that are not the divisor sum of any number. For $n>1$ we have $\sigma(n)>n$, and we can quickly see that $2$, $3$, and $5$ (for example) are not the sum of the divisors of any number.

Comment: Hi guys, could you help me with this question?. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797708/is-sigman-injective-in-set-a-left-n-in-mathbbn-mboxn-is-odd-and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injective would mean that no two distinct numbers have the same sum of divisors. If there are two distinct numbers whose divisors have the same sum, those would serve as a counterexample to show the function is not injective.

There are many such counterexamples, the smallest is $\sigma(6)=\sigma(11)=12$

Comment: thanks for taking me out of doubt friend.