# How to calculate the number of occurences of $\sigma_1(n)$ (divisor function)?

Tags: number-theory

$\sigma_1(n)$ denotes the divisor function.
More precisely is it possible to calculate the number of cases where the sum of the divisors is identical?
For example it exists 3 cases where the sum of the divisors is equal to $24$, for $n=14$, $n'=15$ and $n''=23$ because $\sigma_1(14)=24$, $\sigma_1(15)=24$ and $\sigma_1(23)=24$.

I think the number of cases where the sum of the divisors is identical tends to infinity as $\sigma(n)$ tends to infinity but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: If you find the number of times $\sigma_1(n)$ is equal to $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$ (maybe a few more?), then you can very likely search for the sequence in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org), and find a lot of results and conjectures about it.

Comment: For a similar question see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782607/sigman-is-injective). It also points to OEIS, namely [A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203). Note that $\sigma_1(n)=\sigma(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

I took Arthur's advice and found https://oeis.org/A054973.

Comment: [A007368](http://oeis.org/A007368) is also relevant.